# Programatically remove "custom xml data" from Office docs in SP?

Tags: powershell, xml, office

In Word 2013, if you open a document there's an option to "Check for Issues" and this gives you the option to remove custom XML data. Is there a way to achieve this programmatically with powershell?

My issue is that we have a set of document libraries that have went through several iterations of metadata structure. We're seeing some strange behavior when trying to update the document metadata. Removing the custom XML data fixes these issues but we have thousands of documents so opening each one in Word isn't a very realistic option.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at the [OpenXML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx)

With this library, opening DOCX documents and editing them is pretty easy, and, more importantly, can be done without the need to have Word installed, unlike the previous DOC format which required you to instantiate a Word COM object (which has always been a no go for server side solutions).

Once you get familiar with the library, then you can cycle through all the documents stored in the SP document library and edit them, then save back the updated document.